# in extjs4, how to add a record to database? How php can received the data from ajax data(json format) translated by post method?

Tags: php, ajax, json, extjs4

How php can received the data from ajax data(json format) translated by post method?
I just want the client can send data from client side to the server via ajax method with json as data format.

Below is my code, // line I can add a data on store but the data could not add on database
javascript:

```
    AddBtnClick: function(btn, event){
    var friendstore= this.getGrid().getStore();
    var grid = Ext.ComponentManager.get('searchfriendgrid');
    var selModel = grid.getSelectionModel();
    if(!selModel.hasSelection()){
        Ext.Msg.alert('', '');
    }else{
        //var store = grid.getStore();
        var record=selModel.getLastSelected();

        friendstore.add(record);  //

    }
        formpanel.close();                      /////////////////**
    }
```

php :

```
    public function jsonCreateFriendAction() {
    print_r($_POST['data']);
    print_r($_POST['data']['friendname']);
    //in reality here is some database action, 
    //I find my backend do not received any data from my from end
    //print nothing here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the post getting to the server? You can use firebug to look at the network traffic

If there is no named post variable, you can use

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

to get the posted data then

```
$phpobject = json_decode($data)
```

to transform it to a php object

Comment: I want the client side post data to server side, but my server do not get any data from client. I could not use file_get_contents("php://input");

Comment: well you need to tell extjs to use the proxy to send the data to the server. you probably want to use store.sync()